# Don't want parent to inherit from sub-folder

Tags: sharepoint-online, column, inheritance, subfolders

There is some columns I want to have in my sub-folder, but the parent-folder automatically inherit these. Is it possible to have columns in the sub-folder, but not in the parent-folder?

Here May is the sub-folder, and in this folder I want "status", but I does not need that column in "2021 Documents"

[image: Here May is the sub-folder, and in this folder I want "status", but I does not need that column in "2021 Documents".]

Answer (score 0):

Go to advanced settings for the library and check "**Per-Location View Settings**".

[image]

Here you should be able to set that the top in your hierarchy only uses a view that shows the column, and then set another view for all the others sub folders.

- [Configure the availability of views for a location in the site hierarchy](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-the-availability-of-views-for-a-location-in-the-site-hierarchy-7930b539-55af-4b2f-8d6e-4e0cf263193c?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us)
- [Per-location view settings don't work at the folder level in
  SharePoint 2013, SharePoint 2010, and SharePoint Online](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/sharepoint/troubleshoot/lists-and-libraries/per-location-view-settings-fail-working)